# Git push give an error: HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403 LimitedUploadSize

Tags: azure, github

I push a commit but get this error. I don't know why yesterday It still works

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set-upstream origin ...My remote branch
POST git-receive-pack (343671 bytes)

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403 LimitedUploadSize
Pushing to https://.....my remote URL

Everything up-to-date

Completed with errors, see above.

Thank everyone!

Comment: It have been resolved because of Git limit size. I just push each image per push action instead all image one time. It's works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some hard limits for file and repository sizes on GitHub.

Quoting the [official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files#blocked-pushes-for-large-files):

> **Warning for files larger than 50 MB**
>
> If you attempt to add or update a
> file that is larger than 50 MB, you will receive a warning from Git.
> The changes will still successfully push to your repository, but you
> can consider removing the commit to minimize performance impact. For
> more information, see "[Removing files from a repository's history](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history)."
>
> **Blocked pushes for large files**
>
> GitHub blocks pushes that exceed 100
> MB.

Additional references:

- [File and repository size limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota#file-and-repository-size-limitations)
- [New size limits for Git repositories and files as of Sept 2020](https://backlog.com/blog/new-size-limits-git-repositories-files-sept-2020)